# WeblGL - Drawing Tons of moving Images with Little CPU

Tags: performance, image, 2d, gpu, webgl

I've made a game using the Canvas element and with 300+ images being drawn every frame I am forced to make it run at <20 fps and it takes 60+% CPU:

So I guess my best option is to switch to WebGL. I've been scavenging the web, looking for tutorials and examples. It's kinda complex stuff but I managed to hack together a working source.

```
<!-- Licensed under a BSD license. See license.html for license -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WebGL - 2D Image</title>
<link type="text/css" href="http://games.greggman.com/downloads/examples/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://games.greggman.com/downloads/examples/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = main;

function main() {
  image = new Image();
  image.src = "http://games.greggman.com/downloads/examples/webgl/resources/leaves.jpg";  // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
  image.onload = function() {
    setUp();
    setInterval(function(){
        x1 += 1;
        y1 += 1
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
                //render(image, x1+i*5, y1+e*5);
                gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

                 // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
                setRectangle(gl, x1+i*5, y1+e*5, image.width, image.height);

                // Draw the rectangle.
                 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            }
        }
    },1000/60);
  }
}
var x1 = 0;
var y1 = 0;
var image;
var canvas;
var gl;
var texture;
function setUp() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    // setup GLSL program
  vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
  fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");
  program = createProgram(gl, [vertexShader, fragmentShader]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

    // lookup uniforms
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Create a texture.
  texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the image into the texture.
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

 // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);





  // Create a buffer for the position of the rectangle corners.
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

function render(image, x, y) {

}

function randomInt(range) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

</script>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

   // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
   vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

   // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
   vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

   gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

   // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader
   // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
</script></script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

It draws 300 images but takes only 1/2 the CPU of using the normal canvas. Now that's not too bad but it's still not good enough.
Am I doing something wrong or unnecessary? Is there a way I can ease of the CPU by doing calculations in the GPU or caching them?
I've researched in shaders and would it be possible to use a shader to store textures and coordinates and just input an array to the shader to set location points of each image I need to draw?

Thanks,
I hope there's an easy solution to this madness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to draw 300 (different) Images? Or just 300 Rectangles with the same texture? (this is what you are currently doing)

In general your code is very inefficent because of multiple reasons:

- Instead of creating a buffer once and reusing it you allocate 300 new Float32Array arrays per frame (in `setRectangle()`)
- Instead of creating 300 small buffers for 300 objects you can put all your vertex information within an single buffer and than draw everything at once (this only works if you don't want to draw every object with a different texture)
- You are switching the texture state for each object (`glBindTexture`). Its better to setup textures once and than draw a batch of objects with the same textures

A bit more optimized version of you code would look like:

```
// called once
setup() {
  // load and setup texture
  // create vertex buffer object for your vertex data
  // setup shader
}

// called every frame
display() {
  gl.useProgram(..) // set shader
  gl.bindTexture(..) // set texture
  gl.bindBuffer(..) // set buffer
  gl.drawArrays(0, 1800) // draw all you object in one step
}
```

For the case that you really want to draw each object with another texture it is a bit more complicated. But again you have multiple options to optimze:

- combine multiple textures in on file. E.g you can combine 16 128x128 textures in a single 512x512 texture file. In this case you have to update the texture coordinates of you objects to match the texture
- use multiple texture units and decide within the shader which unit should be used.
- if you have multiple objects that use the same texture you can sort your objects so that you can draw these objects in one step.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be 300 different textures. This is my game I'm planning on switching to WebGL:
http://cl.ly/image/3h1J200K091I

I'll try out your suggestions when I get off work! In the meantime, you get a green checkmark.

I just hope I can figure out how to re-use buffers and get texture usage in the shader.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) or [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Mark_Kilgard/using-vertex-bufferobjectswell) can help you improving your buffers. Both links are about OpenGL written in C. However it shouldn't be too hard to transfer this to webGl (function names are nearly identical).